# How to convert number into character array in java without using any java inbuilt function

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, recursion

I am preparing for an interview and I am not able to solve one of the problem.
Below is the problem:

> Take number and print it as character one by one without using any inbuilt java conversion function.
>   Below is the example lets say you have one numnber 1234 and now write function to take this number as integer and print character array {1,2,3,4}.

It asked to write this function without using any inbuilt java conversion
Please let me if any one knows how to solve it.

Comment: I know, but [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Using the divide and modulo operation you can do it

Comment: @keppil, thats an awesome link. Going down my bookmark ,will come in handy in such cases. Lol

Comment: We do expect a wee bit of effort on your part, even if the code you wrote is completely broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the general idea of the algorithm, modify it to create a char array instead of printing the results:

```
void printNumber(int n) {
    if (n < 10)
        System.out.println(n);
    else {
        printNumber(n / 10);
        System.out.println(n % 10);
    }
}
```

I wrote it using a recursive algorithm, because I fancy recursion ... but it's trivial to convert this to an iterative solution.

Comment: With respect, i dont think giving cooked up code samples is a good idea. :-)

Comment: @MukulGoel OP stated that this is practice for an interview, it's not like it's homework - I don't see a problem giving a straight answer this time.

Comment: Hmmm.. Seems legit.. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Oscar for your answer. I really appreciate it. @Keppil I was aware that how to convert and print character using Java inbuilt function only.

Comment: this wont work with negative numbers?

Comment: @tb It won't. Nor will it work for decimal numbers, or hexadecimal numbers, or octal numbers. The function, as defined above, will work only for base-10 integer values >= 0. For other input types, it's better to stick to a string-based approach and treat the number as a sequence of characters. But I believe the OP doesn't need the solution to be so generic, it's only a simple interview question after all.

Answer (score 8):

Hint :

> Modulo by 10 gives last digit
>
> Division by 10 of an integer removes its last digit.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the number digit by digit and use switch-case clauses to decide which character you have to map it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int number = 500;
    final int base = 10; // the number system, in your case: decimal
    int tmp = number; // create a temporary variable for processing
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // create a buffer for your textual representation (or calc the length beforehand)
    //
    do {
        int digit = tmp % base; // get the last digit
        sb.append(digit); // attach it to your character buffer
        tmp /= base; // remove the numbers last digit
    } while (tmp != 0); // stop when there is no more character but when the number is 0, you have to execute it once
    sb.reverse(); // now flip the characters because it was written to from behind
    //
    String numText = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(numText);
    //
    char[] chars = numText.toCharArray();
    sb = new StringBuilder("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        char c = chars[i];
        sb.append(c);
        if (i != chars.length - 1) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
    }
    sb.append("}");
    //
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: According to question, toCharArray is probably not allowed here. If you use toCharArray, you could also directly do it on ("" + number).

Answer (score 0):

If we follow the restrictions completely, this is a rather nice exercise.

Here is my solution:

```
static char[] getCharArrayFromInt(int value) {
    if (value == 0)
        return new char[]{'0'};
    if (value == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return new char[]{'-', '2', '1', '4', '7', '4', '8', '3', '6', '4', '8'};
    int signValue = 0;
    if (value < 0) {
        signValue = 1;
        value *= -1;
    }
    char[] result = new char[signValue + (int) (Math.log10(value) + 1)];
    // to be correct, we need a switch/function here. but for the length, lets reduce it
    if (signValue == 1)
        result[0] = '-';
    for (int i = result.length - 1; i >= 0 + signValue; --i) {
        result[i] = (char) ((value % 10) + '0');
        // to be correct, we need a switch here. but for the length, lets reduce it
        value /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It violates the "without using any inbuilt java conversion function" two times, marked in the source. This was only to shorten the program. It is very clear and easy to write a function with a switch for this parts.

The functions should be valid for the complete Integer range.

But honestly, I do not think one could make this solution in 10 min in a job interview. You should start discussing about writing clean code pays off the most and why is it better to avoid such things as shown above.

--tb